# How to update my table using Arithmetic Operator by using update_batch in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to update my table using update batch.

so I have this table columns

```
ID | Description | Total
1      Test 1       10
2      Test 2       15
3      Test 3       20
```

My main goal is to update the `Total` column using update batch, so i will not need to update them one by one.

so I don't have to do this one by one on my loop, instead i can just do update_batch

```
UPDATE table
SET Total = Total + 10
WHERE ID = 1;

UPDATE table
SET Total = Total + 25
WHERE ID = 2;

UPDATE table
SET Total = Total + 30
WHERE ID = 3;
```

How can I do this using update_batch?

Here is the code the I currently have

Controller:

```
        foreach($total_debit as $list){
            $data[] = array(
                 "ID" => $list->ID,
                 "Total" => Total + $list->value_to_be_added, //10
            );
         }

      $this->Employee_model->update_total_value($data);
```

Model:

```
    public function update_total_value($data){
        $this->db->update_batch('employees', $data,"ID");
    }
```

Can anyone help me if this is possible to do?

Comment: follow the documentation, see: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#CI_DB_query_builder::update_batch

Comment: I already followed that sir, my query is working, i just need to know if how can i add a arithmetic operator in my query using the update batch.

Comment: what's the input for this?  there are a lot of ways that you can use based on the use case, tell us more about how do you want to use the program.